# Live Services: Unable to regenerate client secret for WNS

Tags: wns

Im trying to regenerate my client secret at the url account.live.com/developers/applications/appsettings/* for my app (for push notification). When I click regenerate, it is stuck with 'Saving...' WHen I was inspecting the apge, I see the following error.

devPortalPackage_9SFHnFq2hYQlQAo6KyjLzw2.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'BICI' of undefined

devPortalPackage_9SFHnFq2hYQlQAo6KyjLzw2.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: $BSI.reportEvent is not a function

Thoughts how to over come this? I tried on a chrome/Mac, Chrome/Windows and IE/Windows, the issue remains the same. 
Appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try navigating to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList and click on your app, and see if that works?

I think the account.live.com/developers/* site is old which is why you are running into issues. My account redirects me to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com.